# curl: (52) Empty reply from server for mongodb

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the MongoDB connection information
mongo_host="172.16.10.10"
mongo_port="27017"
mongo_db="user_info_remote"
mongo_collection="user_info"

# Extract user information from /etc/passwd for users with UID greater than 500 and insert it into MongoDB
awk -F: '$3>=500 {print "{\"username\":\""$1"\",\"uid\":"$3",\"gid\":"$4",\"home\":\""$6"\",\"shell\":\""$7"\"}"}' /etc/passwd \
  | while read user_info; do
    curl -vvv -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$user_info" "http://$mongo_host:$mongo_port/$mongo_db/$mongo_collection"
  done

# Echo a message to the console
echo "User information stored in MongoDB"
```

**Here is the script I was trying to execute but it is giving the below error**

------------------logs from the command line --------------

```
*   Trying 172.16.10.10..

* TCP_NODELAY set

* Connected to 172.16.10.10 (172.16.10.10) port 27017 (#0)

\> POST /user_info_remote/user_info HTTP/1.1

\> Host: 172.16.10.10:27017

\> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1

\> Accept: */*

\> Content-Type: application/json

\> Content-Length: 86

\>

* upload completely sent off: 86 out of 86 bytes

* Empty reply from server

* Connection #0 to host 172.16.10.10 left intact

curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

User information stored in MongoDB

can any one guide me ? I am new at mongo

Here, note that, mongo db configuration file bind is configure for all ip4 IP and I check from remove machines using telnet and curl and port is open.

```
curl -vv telnet://172.16.10.10:27017

* Rebuilt URL to: telnet://172.16.10.10:27017/

*   Trying 172.16.10.10...

* TCP_NODELAY set

* Connected to 172.16.10.10 (172.16.10.10) port 27017 (#0)
```

I am trying to build a script that will collect user info from cat /etc/passwd file and store that data to MongoDB database.

Comment: Standard tool for qurying mongodb is `mongo`, why you don't use it ?

Comment: I have 300+  of servers and for that I may have to install package in all that machine so I was wondering if there is any other alternate way

Comment: Atlas has a [Data API](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api/) that supports HTTP requests. However, if you are running your own instance of MongoDB, you will need a [supported driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/) or [install](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongosh) the new shell [mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell) to connect and query.